# Solving a system of congruent equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem

1.$$10x\equiv 34 \pmod{63}$$

2.$$11x\equiv 44 \pmod{64}$$

3.$$12x\equiv 54 \pmod{65}$$

How am I supposed to solve it? I know that use of the Chinese remainder theorem is not allowed in this case because 'x' doesn't appear solely in the equations.

after using some modular arithmetic I get:

1. $2x\equiv 9 \pmod 5$
2. $x\equiv 4 \pmod 2$
3. $5x\equiv 17 \pmod 7$

How do I continue?

Comment: a keyword is the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Why wouldn't the Chinese remainder theorem be allowed?

Comment: why would it? x doesn't apeear by itself but as 2x or 5x...

Comment: Handle the individual congruences first individually. Then apply the CRT. The first step is automatic, so we can say that this is just CRT.

Comment: What did you do to get those congruences modulo $5,2$ and $7$. That looks wrong. Please add an explanation. Then we can pinpoint your difficulty/confusion/whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$10\times 19 \equiv 1 \pmod{63}$$
$$11\times 35 \equiv 1 \pmod{64}$$
$$12\times 38 \equiv 1 \pmod{65}$$

Comment: i.e.: use modular inverse

Comment: sorry doesn't ring a bell. Also how did you manga to find those numbers?

Answer (score 2):

First thing to ask is whether you can simplify any of the congruences. We have that if $ac\equiv bc \pmod{m}$ and $\gcd(m,c)=d$, (i.e., if $ac\equiv bc \pmod{m'c}$, where $m=m'c$) then we can simplify by dividing through in the congruence by $d$ thus:
$$a\equiv b \pmod{\frac{m}{d}}\tag{1}$$
If you check this $\gcd$ condition you find you cannot do this for any of your congruences.

If $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then the linear congruence 
$$ax\equiv b \pmod{m}\tag{2}$$
has a unique solution. That is only one of $0$, $1,\dotsc,m-1$  makes the product $ax$ congruent $b$ modulo $m$. As a special case if we let $b=1$ we get 
$$ax\equiv 1 \pmod{m}\tag{3}$$ 
with the unique solution of this congruence being termed the *reciprocal* of $a$ modulo $m$.

Now you should note that $\gcd(10,63)=\gcd(11,64)=\gcd(12,65)=1$, and so each of the congruences has a unique solution of $(3)$ thus:
\begin{align*}
10\cdot 19 &\equiv 1 \pmod{63}\\
11\cdot 35 &\equiv 1 \pmod{64}\\
12\cdot 38 &\equiv 1 \pmod{65}
\end{align*}
Now you have the inverses $19$, $35$ and $38$ respectively, you can simply multiply the original congruences by them to isolate $x$ thus:
\begin{align*}
10\cdot 19x &\equiv 1\cdot x \equiv 34\cdot 19 \equiv 16\pmod{63}\\
11\cdot 35x &\equiv 1\cdot x \equiv 44\cdot 35 \equiv 4\pmod{64}\\
12\cdot 38x &\equiv 1\cdot x \equiv 54\cdot 38 \equiv 37\pmod{65}
\end{align*}
Since the moduli are pairwise coprime, (i.e., $\gcd(63,64)=\gcd(63,65)=\gcd(64,65)=1$), you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to uniquely solve your system modulo the product of the moduli, $M=63\cdot64\cdot65=262080$. Let $M_i=\frac{M}{m_i}$, where $m_1=63$, $m_2=64$, $m_3=65$. Then  $M_1=64\cdot65=4160$, $M_2=63\cdot65=4095$, $M_3=63\cdot64=4032$. Now each $M_i$ has a unique reciprocal, $M_i'$, modulo $m_i$, since $\gcd(M_i,m_i)=1$, so letting 
$$x=16\cdot M_1M_1'+4\cdot M_2M_2'+37\cdot M_3M_3'$$
then since $M_i\equiv0\pmod{m_k}$ if $i\neq k$, we have

\begin{align*}
x &\equiv 16\cdot M_1M_1'\equiv 16\pmod{63}\\
x & \equiv 4\cdot M_2M_2'\equiv 4\pmod{64}\\
x &\equiv 37\cdot M_3M_3'\equiv 37\pmod{65}
\end{align*}

So we need to solve for the modular inverses $M_i'$
\begin{align*}
4160\cdot M_1' &\equiv4160\cdot 32\equiv 1\pmod{63}\\
4095\cdot M_2' &\equiv4095\cdot  63\equiv 1\pmod{64}\\
4032\cdot M_3' &\equiv4032\cdot 33\equiv 1\pmod{65}
\end{align*}
so our solution is then
$$x=16\cdot 4160\cdot 32+4\cdot 4095\cdot  63+37\cdot 4032\cdot 33=8084932$$
and so
$$x\equiv8084932\equiv 222532\pmod{262080}$$
Therefore $x=222532$ is the smallest solution to the set of congruences.

Comment: Thanks. the only part I didn't understand is how did you find the inverses?

Comment: One way of finding these is the Euclidean algorithm:
$63=6\cdot10+3\rightarrow10=3\cdot3+1$. Therefore working back $1=10-3\cdot3=10-3(63-6\cdot10)=19\cdot10-3\cdot63$, or $19\cdot10-1=3\cdot63$. Viewing this modulo $63$ we have $19\cdot10\equiv1\pmod{63}$. Similar for the others. You could also use Euler's theorem: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: I don't understand. Euler's theorem states that 'a' to the power of {function of euler of n} modulu n is congruent to 1 modulu n.however for this condition to exist I need to assume(which I absolutely can't) that a, which in the equation is 10x, 11x,12x is coprime to n.

Comment: Your $(a,m)$ pairs are $(10,63)$, $(11,64)$, $(12,65)$, and they all satisfy $\gcd(a,m)=1$ so you can use Euler's theorem here. The Euler totient function, $\phi(n)$ is the total of numbers $1\le j\le n$ such that $\gcd(j,n)=1$. Euler's theorem then says $a^{\phi (m)}\equiv 1\pmod {m}$. Then $a^{\phi (m)-1}\equiv a^{-1}\pmod {m}$. For $(10,63)$: $\phi(63)=36$, so $10^{\phi (63)-1}=10^{36-1}=10^{35}=(10^5)^7=(100000)^7\equiv 19^7=893871739\equiv19\pmod {63}$, thus $10^{-1}=19$. Of course if $\gcd(a,m)\ne1$ you can't use Euler, as $a$ needs to be in $(\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z})^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Since Math Lover hint "didn't ring a bell", here is hint n°2.

Remember these properties of modulo:

$$x\equiv y \pmod n \implies ax\equiv ay\pmod n$$
$$x\equiv y \pmod n \land x\equiv z\pmod n \implies y\equiv z\pmod n$$

Now, using these 2 equations:

$$10*19\equiv 1 \pmod {63} $$
$$10x\equiv 34 \pmod {63}$$

Find 2 ways to write:

$$10*19*x\equiv ? \pmod {63}$$

Doing the same with the other equations should help you to make x "appear solely in the equations"

Comment: but how did you find the inverses

Answer (score 0):

Consider (1). We must find a number $a$ where $0\leq a\leq 62$ such that $10a\equiv 1\bmod 63$ in order to isolate $x$. By a lot of trial and error we find that $a=19$. Similarly, for (2) and (3) we find that $a=35$ and $a=38$. (Incidentally, this is what MathLover's hint alludes to.)

So now, having performed this multiplication,
 - we reduce the system to the following congruences $$x\equiv 34\cdot 19\equiv 16\bmod 63,$$ $$x\equiv 44\cdot 35\equiv 4\bmod 64,$$ $$x\equiv 54\cdot 38\equiv 37\bmod 65.$$

Now, since $63,64,65$ are mutually co-prime, we may apply Chinese remainder theorem which I shall do in a bit. First, try having a go yourself.